# How to get sauron-org to work for org-mode events?

Tags: org-mode

For some reason I can't get Sauron to see my org-mode events.  I can see that the sauron-org module has started though.  Is there something else I need to enable/turn on to get Sauron to see org-mode events?

I have `(require 'sauron)` in my init, and when I start sauron, it reports that the relevant sauron-org module is loaded, but I never get any sauron notifications of events from org.

The expected behaviour is that it would notify me 15 minutes, 10 minutes, 5 minutes, 2 minutes before events scheduled in org-mode.

Comment: I'm disappointed that three people have voted to close, but none have bothered to leave a comment.  You are more likely to get help if you provide an explanation of how you set up Sauron (with the relevant lines from your init file perhaps) and the behavior you are experiencing vs what you were expecting.  If you provide enough info to reproduce your problem, it will be much easier to help you fix it.

Comment: Not sure what to add. I have (require 'sauron) in my init, and when I start sauron, it reports that the relevant sauron-org module is loaded, but I never get any sauron notifications of events from org. The expected behaviour is that it would notify me 15 minutes, 10 minutes, 5 minutes, 2 minutes before events scheduled in org-mode.

Comment: @BeSlayed: Your comment should have been part of the question in the first place.  That's why people downvoted the question; it's missing the relevant details.

Comment: I suspect part of the lack-of-response problem is that it's not clear what to do -- in part because `sauron` is not in widespread use.  For everyone's reference, here are links to the [GitHub page](https://github.com/djcb/sauron), the [EmacsWiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Sauron), and a [blog post about `sauron`](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2011/12/sauron-keeping-eye-on-whats-going-on.html).

Comment: I think it would be useful to provide a minimum working (or loading in this case) example of your init file. One way to do this would be to move your `.emacs` to `.emacs.bk` and make a new file containing only lines required to make `sauron` load and post that as part of your question.